# How do I get master key in ssl session in java?

Tags: java, jsse

I have a sslscoket as server in my application and I am running java 1.6. 
I need the master secret key used during handshake to implement the MS-CHAP challenge response and so on.
I have read that "The value of this master secret is known only to the underlying secure socket implementation and is not exposed through the SSLSession API"

How can I get the value of the master secret?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I have managed to get the master secret used in the TLS hanshake.
It is possible to get it using reflection and SSLSessionImpl.class

Answer (score 2):

```
Enumeration<byte[]> e = sslContext.sessionContext().getIds();
    while ( e.hasMoreElements() ) {
        byte[] b = e.nextElement();
        System.out.println("session id: " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(b).toLowerCase());
        SSLSession session = sslContext.sessionContext().getSession(b);
        Class<?> c = Class.forName("sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl");
        Field masterSecretField = c.getDeclaredField("masterSecret");
        masterSecretField.setAccessible(true);
        SecretKey k = (SecretKey)masterSecretField.get(session);
        System.out.println("secret: " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(k.getEncoded()).toLowerCase());

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

It isn't available via the API. As your quotation says.

NB The master secret is not a key.

Comment: Is there any option to make this in java? Another API?

Comment: What part of "you can't" didn't you understand?

Comment: I understand, thank you for be so nice, but I can not understand how is possible that they implement the API for SSL and they don't provide means to implement MS-CHAP over it.

Comment: Maybe the SSL master key has nothing to do with MS-CHAP?

Comment: As far as I understand the "TLS Inner Application Extension" the Implicit challenge needed in MS-CHAP. "When a challenge-based authentication mechanism is used, both client and server use the TLS PRF function to generate as many octets as are required for the challenge, using the constant string "inner application challenge", based on the then-current master secret and random values established during the initial handshake phase"

Comment: I have not downvoted your answer but I have unaccepted it since I found the way to do it. It is explained in my answer if you need more indications just tell me.